# htaccess error 500 if empty variable (php)

Tags: php, .htaccess

/product/blabla is ok
/product/ give a "500 internal error"

```
RewriteRule product/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) product.php?c=$1 [L]

if ($_GET['c']){
 ....
}
else{
  ?>
  <script>document.location.href="<?=$racine;?>"</script>
  <?
}
```

Comment: Well, `/product/` does not match `product/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)`, so **who knows what code is getting executed there!?**

Comment: Maybe it is executing index.php in product/ directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteRule product/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) product.php?c=$1 [L]
RewriteRule product/ product.php [L]

if (isset($_GET['c'])){
 ....
}
else{
  ?>
  <script>document.location.href="<?=$racine;?>"</script>
  <?
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this may help you.

Rewrite your `.htaccess` to

```
RewriteRule product/^$|([0-9a-zA-Z]+) product.php?c=$1 [L]
```

**^$|([0-9a-zA-Z]+)** will check for empty string or a string. So `product/` too will work

Comment: `^` is the beginning of the string. I don't think *the beginning of the string* will occur in the middle of the string. `product/^$` never matches anything, only `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` will always match *anything*!

Comment: @deceze, ^$ is represents an empty string. so I think `product/` or `product/blahblah` will redirect to same path. The question says `/product/` give 500 internal server error. By changing the regex all combinations will lead to product.php

Comment: Yes, the regular expression `^$` matches an empty string. But only if that's the *entire* expression! The expression says "beginning of string immediately followed by end of string". If you have anything else in that expression, it won't match anymore.

Comment: Yeah, because **the first part never matches anything and the second part always matches everything!** See here: http://rubular.com/r/83FZ0HS1zb This *shouldn't* match, but it does!